# select columns that match designated number in excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
HB  1   2   3   4
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0.1 0
7   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0
```

I have a table like this but with much larger number of columns and rows. I want to select columns and rows based on a set of numbers in another sheet shown below. Select the columns (and rows) if the first row (and first column) in the above table matches the number listed in the below table. And add the values for the selected intersection of columns and rows together.

```
ColumntoSelect
2
4
8
23
```

How to achieve that in excel? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a SUMPRODUCT with a MATCH to tell which rows and columns are desired:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:$X$1,$B$12:$B$15,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$9,$D$12:$D$15,0))*$B$2:$X$9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. My data actually have 5000*5000 which equals 25 million. When I use your formula, some of the calculation showed a problem called "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated"

Comment: Then you will need vba.  You will need to make your own attempt at the vba.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  Try to write it on your own and come back with a new question when you get stuck.  Post your example and the code you have tried.  Formulas will not get you there with that large of a dataset.